# How to include hundreds of folders in a Makefile?

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I'm working on a C++ project at work where we need to develop a small piece for a larger application. We were given headers and static libraries for all of the code that we should need to reference. These are strewn throughout multiple folders and we placed all of that inside a common folder.

When writing our code, we'll need to include the headers and libraries as a part of our compilation process. Is there an elegant solution to doing this in a Makefile, or do I have to explicitly list each include folder with -I , each library folder with -L , and each library with -l?

Or is there an alternative to a Makefile that might make sense for this?

Edit: Here is an example of the folder structure:

```
common
    folder1
        subfolder1
            include
            libs
        subfolder2
        ...
        subfolder10
    folder2
        ...
    ...
    folder10
code
    makefile
    ourStuff
```

There are multiple levels of folders under common containing headers and libraries. We need to include code from there.

It was also asked why we don't just explicitly list the path in our #include statements. This code will be living in the main application once we're done, and it doesn't exactly follow the folder structure we were given.

Comment: Why not use relative paths for those headers in your `#include` statements, and only specify the roots using the `-I` compiler flags? Can you give an example of those directory structures, and what you currently have in your code and makefiles please?

Comment: I don't think I really understand what you want to do, but the short answer is that there's no way make can somehow guess or intuit the right locations for header files, libraries, etc. given no other information.  You say you have "placed all of that inside a common folder", so I guess I don't understand where these "hundreds of folders" are coming from.  I think you'll have to provide some sort of concrete example of your situation before we can help.

Comment: @MadScientist Well, `VPATH` is a way, but I don't necessarily recommend that, since it's very dangerous to get collisions accidentially.

Comment: You could run `find` to set a variable in the makefile that lists all the folders and then transform it into lots of flags.  But usually if the headers are in lots of folders, you're supposed to include the paths like @πάνταῥεῖ said.  You'll get collisions when headers have the same name in different folders and it will be annoying to find the headers given just their name in code.

Comment: use cmake instead. I do not use make for quite a long time now and switching to something designed for humans was a very good decision

Comment: @Raymond O. - I'd create links of the needed include files in a common include directory, and links of the library files in a common library directory.

Comment: VPATH won't intuit locations for you.  You still have to write all the locations down, in the VPATH.  Also, VPATH only tells _make_ where to find things.  It won't tell your _compiler_ or _linker_ where to find things.

Comment: Demand packaging.  If you need a library, put it in /usr/lib, don't shoe-horn it into your source tree.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, demanding packaging is the correct solution. Except you don't to put them under `/usr`. `/usr/local` is better. Being allowed to set a `PREFIX` options during compilation/installation is the way to go. Then it is just a matter of adding `-I $PREFIX/include` to `CPPFLAGS` and `-L $PREFIX/lib` to `LDFLAGS` in the `Makefile`. TLDR: Your directory structure is wrong, fix it, don't mess with the Makefile.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Putting things into usr/lib will not work when cross-compiling, which is what most C/C++ programmers do nowadays for embedded systems work.

Comment: @HAL9000 And what when you cross-compile?

Comment: @Vroomfondel Then you install the libraries in /target/arch/ and ensure that `-L/target/arch/lib` in in LDFLAGS and `-I/target/arch/include is in CPPFLAGS`.  The point is that packaging issues should not be resolved in the source tree.  Don't cut-n-paste libraries.

Comment: @WilliamPursell `target/arch` is too weak a discriminator for embedded work. In can very well drift off into `../project` or even `../project/V1`. When cross-compiling, having assumptions about the host system as prerequisites gets you in all kinds of trouble. The VCS is the only reality in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Well, given the above structure it's simple enough to generate the things you want.  For example if you want to add all `-I...` flags to `CXXFLAGS`, you can use:

```
INCDIRS := $(wildcard ../common/*/*/include)

CXXFLAGS += $(addprefix -I,$(INCDIRS))
```

Similar for `-L` flags:

```
LIBDIRS := $(wildcard ../common/*/*/libs)

LDFLAGS += $(addprefix -L,$(LIBDIRS))
```

Linking all the libraries is *slightly* more complicated.  Assuming they're all static libraries you can do something like this:

```
LIBFILES := $(notdir $(wildcard ../common/*/*/libs/lib*.a))

LDLIBS += $(patsubst lib%.a,-l%,$(LIBFILES))
```

Of course this is assuming you don't have any naming conflicts / all libraries are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, your question can be formulated like this: "Do I have to write a plethora of include paths or is there some managed/automatic way to do that". The question may pop up in the context of a `makefile` but this is mainly because `make` does not try to cloak the complexity of software building from the programmer. Trying to evade to another build system buys you nothing if the components you are using were not fitted into the larger build algorithm by their original programmers. If you receive pre-configured build parts (e.g. in form of a CMake project) then you save a great deal of work, needing only to tie together some abstraction level high up in the hierarchy. The downside of this is that you are locked in this build methodology now, possibly with more ramifications radiating out into parts of your project where they do as much harm as good. You may want to read this thread here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/407056/the-case-against-path-expressions-in-include-directives

The cheapest way to at least partially achieve what you want to do in `GNUmake` is to use the function `wildcard-rec` (see https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt#call-wildcard-reclist-of-globs) which has a fairly flexible input-output-relation. You can e.g. collect all paths which are of the form `project/component_a/**/include/` in a whole subtree, or all header files in such a path with `project/component_a/**/include/*.h`.

PS: simply `include gmtt.mk` at the top of your makefiles.